# psfrag package and autocad .eps

Tags: psfrag

is there a way use .eps figure from autocad and edit its labels using the psfrag package? I tried with exporting figure from autocad directly to .eps and then, in figure environment, I used \psfrag command as manual says. Here is a simple code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
la figura è:
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
 \psfrag{a}{$y+2$}
 \psfragfig[scale=0.2]{prova.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The file .eps is created using auto cad and it is a simple Line text with the only letter a

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. For us to help you better, could you please provide a minimal working example? in that way we can better understand your problem and try to help you with that. Also, could you give us more information on your issue? For instance, like whether you are using `Latex` or `pdftex` core or something else?

Comment: as the psfrag manual explains you need the strings that are replaced to be single strings in the eps not separate string for each letter separately positioned, so if you are replacing `sin x` it will not work unless the string `(sin x)` is literally in the eps file, so you can check with a text editor which strings are in the EPS. PostScript strings are `(...)` delimited.

Comment: I edit the post and I put a working code